# Use controller variable in view after page reload in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-5.8

I have assigned a variable inside the controller that I want to use in the blade.php after the page is reloaded.

Note: When the user clicks on submit, the page gets reloaded from ajax/javascript inside the assets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry am not sure am getting the question right, if am to understand, want to access your variable from controller on your view.
Let’s say you want to return a dynamic page title on your home or index view from your homecontroller

```
public function index(){
$page_title = “My own title”;
return view(home, compact(‘page_title”);
```

}

Then on your home.blade.php you call access your $page_title with {{ $page_title}}

Comment: Thanks. This is what I was looking for. :)